# How do I use index match to find the first sale that a customer has made?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table: [image]

and I want to find the first order date for each customer.
For this, I have created a new column of customers and deleted the duplicates and tried using the function:

`=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$74686=L2,$I2:$I74688))`

But it doesn't seem to do what I want it to as the cells get larger. 
I feel like I have to use an index match with the min function but I am unsure how to approach this.

Comment: A: Your ranges are not equal of size, B: Make sure to enter it as array formula. > `{=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$74688=L2,$I2:$I74688))}`

Comment: You are almost there, follow @JvdV instructions. To enter the formula as array formula, you need to confirm pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER at same time. And if you got Excel 2019 or higher, you can use function [MINIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599)

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work further down the table. There are occurrences where there is a delivery on the first week but it returns a first order date of 9/01/2017 (week 2)

Comment: Then that means you are probably dragging the formula down and not used absolute references correctly, In fact you made the columns absolute, while rows are kept relative. It should be the other way around: `{=MIN(IF(A$2:A$74688=L2,I$2:I$74688))}`

Comment: @JvdV wow thanks, I kept thinking I had to use an index match for this question.. Thanks a lot for your answers for both my questions today! If you post an answer I can approve it

Comment: Not a problem. Have you looked into Pivot Tables on your earlier question as suggested by @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns? CPU/effortwise it would be your best bet.

Comment: Yeah I had a look, the thing is this is for a task and this is what is required of me. I used the pivot tables to check my results, in particular for the previous question about counts as I was getting some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, it seems that in your current formula:

- You are using ranges that are different in dimensions
- You are using absolute references wrongly (in case you need to drag down)

So the correct formula would be:

```
=MIN(IF(A$2:A$74688=L2,I$2:I$74688))
```

Don't forget to enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>